# How to get rid of spilled coffee scent?

Tags: cleaning

Thought I managed to clean the coffee spill effectively; however, few days later the scent is still there.
At this stage, what is a suitable way to removed coffee scent off a rugged floor?

Comment: Was it black coffee, or coffee with cream, sugar, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Dump a box of baking soda on it, wait a few days, vacuum it up.

Comment: Careful! Baking soda is pretty fine stuff. It can clog vacuum filters very quickly.  Borrow a shop vac for the job, and finish with your household one.

Answer (score 1):

Vinegar can solve the issue as well. Try a 1 to 2 ratio with water.

Comment: Related question:  How do I get rid of vinegar scent?

Comment: I find some coffee grinds take care of the smell.  Time will take care of the smell once it dries.  Or just wipe down with water.

Comment: Also, the vinegar smell will air out. It takes some time, but it goes away completely as it evaporates. I clean my hardwood floors with it (roughly 1/3 cup of vinegar used) and the smell is gone in about 5-6 hours. The mop head however, will need to be washed before it goes away. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @treeNinja OK, then how do I get rid of... nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

Most pet stores, these days, sell enzyme mixtures for eliminating pet odors. These will work on many organic odors, *IF* you haven't already "set" the stain by hitting it with other chemicals. (Even then, they may help. Nothing will ever eliminate all traces of the previous owner's cat from my persian rug, but it's been knocked down to a level that neither I nor my own cats find objectionable. I did have to treat both top and bottom of the rug rather thoughly, though, since the stain had soaked through.)

(By the way, this stuff is great for eliminating sick-room odors as well. Organics are organics.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on, you can do the enzyme cleaner already mentioned (and the kind for laundry has always worked just as well for me) then the next day put baking soda & vacuum it off

Source: my ADD medication has a side effect of making me really good at cleaning, so friends & relatives are always hitting me up for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend baking soda and water solution. Might it until it's a toothpaste like consistency. Spread it, and then wait a day. Clean it up when dry, picking up as much as you can with your hands and then a vacuum and then water and a rag to get the rest.

If that doesn't do the trick follow up with a 2:1 mixture of water and white vinegar. A tiny bit of alcohol can help, but it's not ideal for carpet and it's usually not necessary.

Repeat those two and you will get there. You can try a tough enzymatic cleaner but some of those are rather nasty and they are hit and miss.